# Org mode TODO/DONE font weight

Tags: org-mode

In Org-mode, you can go into column/table view (`C-c C-x C-c`). When doing so, the alignment of text in rows is a little bit off, despite having a monospace font in my startup settings. I figured out this is caused by columns with bold text, which is how tags and TODOs are rendered.

Is there a way to make all fonts (including tags and TODOs) to be normal weight, when in column/table view? An okay compromise would be to disable bold decorations in Org mode altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are ok disabling globally that decorations for face `org-todo` and `org-tag`, adding that on your `init.el` should work:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (interactive)
            (let ((faces '(org-todo org-tag org-done))
                  (mapcar (lambda (f) (set-face-attribute f nil :weight 'normal))
                          faces)))))
```

Be sure to add that after some customized theme loading, because this can be overwritten.

Comment: Hi @Manoel. I've just tried evaluating that, and I get "Invalid face: org-todo". Any idea why?

Comment: Seems that `org-todo` and `org-tag` are defined in some way on `org-faces` instead of `org` module, but even setting `org-faces` as argument to `eval-after-load` this doesn't works well. Maybe these variables are created on the fly. I don't know well the reason, but setup that alternatively as hook for `org-mode` works as expected. Try update the code from the edited answer.

Comment: Much better, that works for me! Would be nice to single it out to only table mode but I can see how that might be tough. Also, you may want to add a line for `'org-done` as well, for posterity, as that is required.  Where did you find all of those org-related face attributes? I just happened to guess `org-done` and got lucky.

Comment: Nice that you asked. I just called `M-x describe-face` on the current cursor position of the text related that you asked, a TODO and a random tag.